# Build XPath using wildcard for changing strings

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am trying to build an XPath for a property that is constantly changing. The number prefix is bound to change sometimes.

Original:

```
//*[@id="MainContent_DXEditor3_I"]
```

which I can query using

```
$x('//*[@id="MainContent_DXEditor3_I"]
```

Intended use: I would like to build the string to handle any number in the sub-string. Example: if the property changes to 'MainContent_DXEditor33_I' or 'MainContent_DXEditor8_IXYZ' - I still want to be able to find the element without having to rebuild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to relax the predicate by using [`starts-with()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-starts-with) :

```
//*[@starts-with(@id, "MainContent_DXEditor")]
```

Comment: Have tried using 'starts-with' but it returns more than a single element which isn't serving the need. I would like to be able to just use wildcard for a single character within the string. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should try to identify a unique parent of the element or save xpath as a string that contains a variable.
These are the 2 possible solutions.

A general selector will return multiple elements, if you identify a unique parent then you are closer and after that you can select any first, second.. last if you have a list.

Comment: The issue is that there are a bunch of fields in a modal popup and all have the same parent. Saving xPath as a string would return all fields that match the criteria. Then I would have to depend on index # rather than being able to use the field specific identifier